# Store Console.Log as Variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to capture an adobe experience ID that is loaded when the site load. I was hoping to log the ID and then pass it to a variable then pass that to a hidden field on a form. I have the code below, but it comes up as undefined for the variable when passing. I'm aware that the variable isn't defined because I guess you can't store a variable as console.log. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```js
<script>
  
var a = console.log(_satellite.getVar("Experience Cloud ID"));

  
 window.onload = function() {
      console.log(a);
   document.getElementById("tfa_1").value = a;
      };

  
  
</script>
```

Comment: You don't need to log for this. Just do `document.getElementById("tfa_1").value = _satellite.getVar("Experience Cloud ID")`

Comment: Why not store it first and then log it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store _satellite.getVar("Experience Cloud ID") in the variable, and then whenever you want, console.log it.

```
var a = _satellite.getVar("Experience Cloud ID");
```

Comment: Welp. Guess I was overthinking it. I will try this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can just store the ID in the variable first, then log that variable's contents.